# Looping the files inside the folder and load data into delta table using databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

1.I have folder inside the blob storage

conatiner--->folder--->2021-10-17---->14-10-20-->filename1.txt,filename2.txt,filename3.parquet

conatiner--->folder--->2021-10-17---->15-10-20-->filename1.parquet,filename2.parquet,filename3.parquet

i need to process all the .txt and .parquet files inside the databricks folder and load the data into delta table using databricks.Can you please help me on this issue?

Some of the .txt file don't have schema .how to define the schema and need to proess the files?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass a wildcard expression that will match your folder structure, something like this (add more `*` characters if necessary):

```py
# read
df = spark.read.parquet("base_path_of_container/folder/*/*/*.parquet")
# write data into Delta
df.write.format("delta").save("path_to_delta")
```

Comment: How to check the file having schema or not? If the file don't have schema we need to attach the schema and process the data into delta table?

Comment: Parquet files have the schema inside the files. If files may have different schema, then you need to specify this setting: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#schema-merging. If you know the schema, then it's better to specify it with `.schema(...)` method - it will make reads faster